# How to hide nav bar in Jqgrid and dynamically reload with new values

Tags: jqgrid, navbar

Is there any way to hide the nav-bar in jqgrid and reappear on selecting the row?
And how to reload the grid dynamically after selecting new value

Comment: Which nav-bar you use? Do you use `navGrid` on bottom pager, on top-pager or on both? Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? It's helpful if you provide demo (in JSFiddle), which shows what you do. The answer could contains modified, which shows the solution of your problem.

Comment: I am using free jqgrid ver. 4.15. I am navGrid bottom pager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show or to hide the navigator bar one need to call show/hide jQuery-method on the div having "navtable" class. The div contains all buttons on the bar. If you use, for example, `pager: "#mypager"` then to hide the navigator bar one need do the following:

```js
$("#mypager").find(".navtable").hide();
```

In more common case you can use the method

```js
var visibilityNavBar = function (show) {
    var pagerSelector = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "pager");
    $(pagerSelector)
        .find(".navtable")[show ? "show" : "hide"]();
};
```

and to call it inside of `onSelectRow` callback

```js
onSelectRow: function (rowid, status) {
    visibilityNavBar.call(this, status);
}
```

To hide the navigator bar initially you can call

```js
visibilityNavBar.call($("#list")[0], status);
```

directly after calling of `navGrid` method.

The demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/s2qkh9mn/ demonstrates the code. On selecting of a row the nav-bar will be displayed, on deselection it will be hidden.

Comment: I have one doubt @Oleg. now that I am able to load the grid, I have to replace the existing gird's rows and columns with new rows and columns. when I am using GridUnload and Griddestroy that new data gets overlapped with old ones.Can you help me resolve this?

Comment: @SandeepRaju: `GridUnload` could be used if the new grid has new columns. I don't understand what kind of "overlapping" you mean.

Comment: Hey @Oleg I have added a picture. 'Programs' and 'id' were my columns in my first grid. Then the grid has to be replaced or reloaded with new columns which I will select for eg. here 'subsystem'. There is an overlapping with old and new grid if you see.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help you without to see the corresponding JavaScript code or better the demo, which reproduces the problem. The picture looks like you didn't called `GridUnload`. After calling of `GridUnload` the whole jqGrid structure will be replaced to initial empty `<table>` which will be not visible on the HTML page.